# Paired Samples T-Test by Day or By Group?

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I am trying to test the impact of a sale initiative on store revenue. I have created 10 matched pairs of stores and then randomly distributed one store in each pair into a test or control group.

I then ran the sale for 21 days within the test group (keeping control constant) and measured relative lift in revenue compared to baseline.

**My questions**

1.) Should I be using a paired t-test based on the previous store matching

2.) Should I be measuring across each day of the test such as:

```
        Control Test
1/1/2017    4   3
1/2/2017    3   4
1/3/2017    1   3
1/4/2017    2   3
1/5/2017    2   4
1/6/2017    1   7
```

Or measuring across my paired markets such as:

```
               Test Control
Market Pair 1   10  5
Market Pair 2   8   3
Market Pair 3   5   1
```

Comment: Would not use t-test. Numbers small. Stores not really paired, assigning a pair does not adjust for relative sales that would occur in each store.

Comment: what is number of test ? 24 or 23 ? please  elaborate your market pair concept. And indicate your important hypotheses you intend to test.